# Get rows with single values using SQlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

By using SQlite, I'd like to get all rows that show in a specific column only one single distinct value. Like from following table:

```
A B
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 1
6 1
7 2
8 4
9 2
```

Here I'd like to get only row Nr. 4 an 8 as there values (3 and 4) occur only once in the entire column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE B IN (SELECT B FROM mytable GROUP BY B HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A)=1)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bd8ce/2).

Subquery will return all B values that are present only once (you could also use `HAVING COUNT(*)=1` in this case), the outer query will return all rows where B is returned by the subquery.